# Movement in darkness - what reduction?

Tags: movement, adnd-2e, content-identification

In darkness, is movement "reduced by ⅓" or "reduced to ⅓"?

**What is the groundspeed velocity of an unladen human in darkness?**
Would they have a movement rate of 8″ or 4″ ?

I have a vague memory that the books mentions both ways, which would be a contradiction.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Enjoy the contradiction…

The ***Dungeon Master's Guide*** (1989) for ***Advanced Dungeons & Dragons, 2nd Edition*** says, "Since one can't see anything in the dark, the safe movement rate of blinded character is immediately slowed **by** 1/3 the normal amount" (119 and emphasis mine). This is confirmed by **Table 73: Terrain Effects by Movement** (124) that has as its column headers **Condition** and **Move Rate Reduced by** [*sic*]. That table's first entry is that darkness causes a 1/3 reduction. This would make a typical human's normal safe movement rate in darkness 8.

On the other hand, in its discussion of the *darkness, 15' radius* spell, the ***Player's Option: Combat & Tactics*** (1994) says, "Creatures moving in total darkness are reduced **to** 1/3 their normal move unless they wish to risk stumbling" (68 and emphasis mine). This would make a typical human's normal safe movement rate in darkness, instead, 4.

### …Then maybe just ignore it?

While *Tactics* is certainly entitled to make this somewhat significant change, in context—in a section entitled **The Effects of Magic on the Battlefield** that covers neither darkness nor movement generally but specific spells—, the sentence to this reader sounds like one author misremembering a detail rather than like the game's designers making a deliberate change to the rules. Were this DM to return to *Second Edition*, he'd stick with the *Dungeon Master's Guide*, rule that 8 is accurate, and chalk up the mention in *Tactics* to an (*ahem*) editorial misstep.

---

***Note:** I did not attempt to compile a complete list of these contradictions, assuming one point of contention sufficient. It's my understanding that TSR published more material for* AD&D2E *than has any other company for any role-playing game ever, which means there's a lot of material to sift through. I support another user's efforts to compile all of its contradictions on this topic.*

Comment: Sometime in the before times I tried compiling the various rules regarding light .. there's not even clear codification of light levels, all a bit of a mess. In the end I house-ruled levels of Bright, Normal, Poor, Dim, Dark; set Dim to reduce _by_ ⅓, and Dark to reduce _to_ ⅓.

Comment: DMG is core, players option is ... well, options.  Not sure if you want to roll with the whole "what is core?" issue though

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I know there was *AD&D 2E* errata, but I'm unaware of an errata hierarchy like in *D&D 3.5E*. Should that be its own question?

Comment: I don't think TSR was organized in the same way, structure wise, as WoTC is nor did they have the web/internet to easily disseminate errata.  I only remember some errata arriving the Dragon Mag.  2e Era I was beginning to do a lot of other things as hobbies / raising little kids / moving so my focus on stuff like that waned a bit.  Not sure if it's worthy of a question.

Comment: 2e errata has been collected at https://www.dragonsfoot.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=19953&sid=8f18dd40865ac8b57979174d4a75a054 — this issue was not addressed.